# Группировка по "Мере" в сводной таблице

Tags: excel, powerbi

Нужна помощь эксперта.
Имеется сводная таблица, в которой в строках - Компаний, в столбцах - Месяца, а в значениях - Мера, которая определеяет сегмент компаний на каждый месяц.Сводная:

[image: сейчас]

Требуется изменить сводную так, чтобы в строках была - Мера, в столбцах - Месяца, а в значениях - доля компаний в каждом сегменте. Вид на рисунке:
[image: Цель].

[В WinRAR содержится excel файл, данные на вкладке Итог](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yR2Er-PnFjBSawMQtOGOLjmF8DpHFse-/view?usp=sharing)

Буду благодарен любой подсказке

Answer (score 0):

```
=СЧЁТЕСЛИ($D:$D;$F5)/СЧЁТЗ($D$3:$D$94)
```

Это приблизительная формула, которая должна быть в окончательной или промежуточной таблице.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]